# Migrating user records and crypted passwords from Devise to Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, authlogic

Does anyone have any experience migrating from Devise to Authlogic, specifically when it comes to dealing with the crypted password? I currently use bcrypt in Devise and will also use bcrypt in Authlogic.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy. I'm assuming you know the fields Authlogic requires. One of them is the password_salt. Make sure that the salt Devise uses is put into the password_salt field.

At the top of your user model, add the following:

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  config.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::BCrypt 
end
```

Also, I'm assuming you already have the BCrypt gem in your gemfile.